# azure custom api include sub properties

Tags: api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a question how to build a custom api script that returns sub objects from related tables.

My table structure [looks like this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/4hwg.png/) ( I'm not allowed to upload an Image :-( ).

My script looks like this (SQL is much much more complex, I make it short for my question):

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {

var sql = "SELECT * FROM [PointsOfInterests] ";

request.service.mssql.query(sql, [],{
   success: function(results) 
    {
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);
    }
});
};
```

My question now is how to include the property "address" to the result?
My reslut object shoud look like this:

```
[
 { 
   id: 123,
   address: 
        {
           City: test
        }
   }
]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your question refers to Windows Azure Mobile Services.

You can do this using a custom API. See [Define custom APIs in Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn303368.aspx).

Use a SQL query that uses joints to return the data you need from both tables. See [Join Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Using Inner Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to learn the syntax.

For instance, you could use a query such as:

```
select a.Id, a.Name, a.Location, b.City, b.PLZ, b.Street
from PointsOfInterest as a
inner join Address as b
on a.AddressId = b.ID
```

and then create a JavaScript object from the result set, with the structure your response message needs.

You might also need to use a [left outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if there are records in "a" which are not related to any records in "b" (optional relationship).